# How does Apple file a patent for a paper shopping bag?

Tags: patentability

[Apple's new "iBag"](http://pdfaiw.uspto.gov/.aiw?docid=20160264304&SectionNum=1&IDKey=EE3349D0F5C8&HomeUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fappft.uspto.gov%2Fnetacgi%2Fnph-Parser%3FSect1%3DPTO1%2526Sect2%3DHITOFF%2526d%3DPG01%2526p%3D1%2526u%3D%25252Fnetahtml%25252FPTO%25252Fsrchnum.html%2526r%3D1%2526f%3DG%2526l%3D50%2526s1%3D%25252220160264304%252522.PGNR.%2526OS%3DDN%2F20160264304%2526RS%3DDN%2F20160264304)

I picked this up reading some blog.  Why... is this even allowed?  It's a paper bag with a handle.

Comment: We are reading the same blog. I suppose it surprises many of us, but it shouldn't. The amount of outrageous patent applications is constantly rising. Which can only mean that there is a small (?) but considerable degree of success.

Answer (score 1):

Reading only the first page of a patent is often not very helpful to understanding what the patent or patent application is covering. In this case, the patent application isn't trying to claim all paper bags, but constructing a paper bag with 60% or greater post consumer content paper. The second thing to remember here is this is only a patent application, not an issued patent. It is common for patent applications to have extremely broad claim language. Should the application ever be granted, it is likely the claims will be narrowed considerably. As for this specific application, it doesn't seem all that novel to me, but I have no specific knowledge in the fabrication of paper bags and how difficult it is to make a paper bag out of paper with 60% post consumer content.